# sources.list - Understanding syntax & structure in Debian

Tags: debian, apt, repository, aptitude

I have generated a sources.list file from http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ with the following parameters:

- Country: New Zealand
- Release: Stable (Wheezy)
- Architecture: 64 bits
- Sources: Main + Security + Updates
- Include source package: No

The output I get is:

```
deb http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian stable main    
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main    
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

My questions are:

1. **Observation:**  The 'base' source (line 1) points to my local repository (NZ) but the wheezy-updates source (line 2) points to the main repository (US?).

   **Question:** Is there any good reason why they cannot both point to my local (NZ) repository? Possible reasons I can assume are that the NZ repository does not contain the wheezy-updates, or that the main repository releases them earlier than the NZ mirror.
2. **Observation:** Line URL in line 2 ends with a trailing slash, compared with the URL in line 1 that does not.

   **Question:** Is the trailing slash required or important for either line 1 or 2?
3. **Observation:** The order of the lines goes:

   1. Base installation source
   2. Base updates source (my understanding is this used to be called volatile?)
   3. Security updates source

   **Question:** Is the order of the lines really all that important? I read [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man5/sources.list.5.html) that:

   > "It is important to list sources in order of preference, with the most
   >   preferred source listed first. Typically this will result in sorting
   >   by speed from fastest to slowest (CD-ROM followed by hosts on a local
   >   network, followed by distant Internet hosts, for example)."

   However, I would have thought that the security updates were more important, so would go on line 1. Or is is really not that much of an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apparently, is a misconfiguration of the script generator, the NZ servers has wheezy-updates:

   http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/

   Since is an error, your next questions are answered too.
2. If I have to guess, this (maybe) has something to do with the first problem. But, IMO, apt adds a trailing slash `/` always. Servers doesn't nags about it `//` = `/`.
3. This only applies to packages that are share the same name **and** version. Example, your company builds some optimized packages (they has their sources intact), no new version should really be done. You just add your company repository to the top, when you want to install that package, it prefers your company server.

   For versions, APT will always select the higher version available. So, you can leave `security` to the end, packages there are newer than `main` and/or `updates`. APT will prefer the higher version that will be either `updates` or `security`.

Comment: Thank you @Braiam, that explains Q3 and partially Q2 for me. Regarding Q1, when I used the generated sources.list as shown, I don't get any apt-get update errors, so I assume **http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian stable main** has a soft link on the mirror that points to **http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/**. But I am still curious to understand why line 1 and 2 should be different mirrors (NZ line 1, and US line 2) rather than the same one.

Comment: @Toby the error is the script generator. The resultant file is a-OK but the script either doesn't know that NZ also have -updates and fallback to US mirror or the way they have to know whenever a mirror has an determinated distribuition.

Comment: you are right. I just tried adding the 'nz' subdomain to line 2 to read **deb http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main** and  'apt-get update' completed without error. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know this Q&A is old, but FWIW there is no longer any real value in hardcoding your closest mirror in the hope of getting the fastest possible performance.

If you use http://httpredir.debian.org/debian as the repo URL it will auto direct you to the best mirror for you (which may not necessarily be the geographically closest one).

The beauty of that is if a new better mirror comes online you will automatically use that and/or if your local mirror goes offline, you won't need to update your sources.list!

Please see http://httpredir.debian.org/ for full details.

Please note, that you still need to use security.debian.org for security updates!